# Dark horizon line between ocean and bottom of HDRi sky

Tags: animation, lighting, hdri, point-clouds

I want to create a simple animation using the camera to fly through clouds (cloud panes, in this case) over a simple ocean. I've never used Blender to create an atmospheric scene before, so I'm starting with a blue plane (the ocean) and an HDRi sky. The result thus far features an annoying black line running between where the HDRi sky begins and the ocean ends. How do I get rid of it?

I have experience with Vue and Bryce and I was hoping I could just dial in some volumetric atmosphere, but with Blender it seems a bit more involved than that. Also I was hoping to add an infinite plane for the ocean, but Blender doesn't seem have them. Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks. Blender 2.93.5 Windows 10

**UPDATE:** Looks like this is peculiar to HDRi environments in Blender. As an alternative, I'm working with Wolf's Real Sky now. Results are great so far.

[image: Example]